# What is mean by Million cycles per second(MCPS)

Tags: c, signal-processing

I have seen some performance figures are represented by MCPS unit, especially in some dsp codec performance.

Can anybody clarify me this?

/kanu__

Comment: Million accept cycles per second.

Comment: @sharptooth - you must mean 0 accept cycles per second ;)

Comment: ok will do it soon ..

but can u please give me an elaborate answer ?

Comment: @Oded: Okay, let it be 0 million accept cycles per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It essentially means that some trivial operation can be done N million times each second. For example, the processor could perform up to N million arithmetic operations of certain kind each second and not more.